# only return records with odd count in a table with sql command

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a warehouse table in my Access database that looks like this:

```
   product_id
       10
       20
       20
       30
       30
       30
       40
       40
       40
       40
```

Now I need an SQL query to return 10, 30 
`product_id`s which have odd count in the table.

```
SELECT product_id, Count(product_id) AS cnt
FROM warehouse
GROUP BY product_id;
```

This query returns the count of each value, but how can I edit it to only return rows with odd `cnt`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a `having` clause with the `mod` operator:

```
SELECT   product_id, COUNT(product_id) AS cnt
FROM     warehouse
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING   COUNT(product_id) MOD 2 = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT product.id, count(product.id) AS cnt FROM  warehouse GROUP BY product.id) 
WHERE (cnt - (Round(cnt/2.0))*2) <> 0;
```

this is my solution , is there a better way ?